# Currvita: Alignment of an introductory sentence in cvlist

Tags: indentation, currvita

I am currently writing my resume using the `currvita` package.

For a single `cvlist` environment, I would like to put an introductory sentence before the listing. I want to skip the label and want the sentence to be aligned at the beginning of the line.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[NoDate]{currvita}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{cv}{CV}

  \begin{cvlist}{My first cvlist}
    \item \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item[Label 1] Item 1
    \item[Label 2] Item 2 
  \end{cvlist}

  \begin{cvlist}{My second cvlist}
    \item \hspace*{-3,7cm} \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \item[Label 1] Item 1
    \item[Label 2] Item 2 
  \end{cvlist}

  
\end{cv}
\end{document}
```

[image: cvlist alignment]

I have now managed to adjust the first line by modifying the `hspace` for the specific item, but the second line now gets a hanging indent. I am not sure if I am on the right track, or if there is a more elegant solution.

Specifically, I have two questions:

- How do I get rid of the indent in the second line?
- Is there a completely different approach to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I have now solved this by using a `parbox`:

```
  \begin{cvlist}{My third cvlist}
    \item \hspace*{-3,6cm} \parbox[t]{14cm}{\lipsum[1][1-3]}
    \vspace{0,2cm}
    \item[Label 1] Item 1
    \item[Label 2] Item 2 
  \end{cvlist}
```

[image]

I'm sure there are more elegant solutions to this and the absolute lengths are not pretty either, but it works :)